# Passing processes into Docker container

Tags: docker, htop

let's say, I'm trying to get 'visible' all processes on docker host inside my container.
Is it possible to pass they in, so ps or htop could make them printed?

Comment: Is this command just about running `ps` from inside a container?  If there's application code involved, can you [edit] the question to include a [mcve], including how you're starting the container?  A key goal of Docker is to isolate the container and host from each other, so a system-monitoring application is often better run outside a container so the isolation features don't cause problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the `--pid` flag and with `--pid=host` you can start container in host's pid namespace:

```
❯ docker run --rm --pid=host debian:buster bash -c 'ls /proc -1 | wc -l'
489
```

Same goes for `docker-compose`:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  test:
    pid: host
```